# session timeout weirdness

Tags: ajax, iis, session, asp-classic, session-timeout

I have a main site where people log-in. This is IIS and the standard session time out of 20 minutes.

There is a live chat facility which appears in a popup window in the same domain. There's no https involved.

Despite the fact that the chat window makes Ajax calls to the server every few seconds (and always get at least one piece of data back) also sends data to the server via Ajax whenever the logged-in user posts a message they are timed out after 20 minutes as if nothing was happening.

Any ideas why this should happen and how to stop it as it's obviously irrational that they are logged out f the site while actively communicating with the server.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to authenticate and keep users logged in?

Comment: AJAX has nasty habit of caching on the browser..... try busting it by sending unique random value on every request and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I've decided to do is use a cookie rather than the site's session variable to check if they're logged in. As this is a chat app, they get an hour when they first open the chat page.
And every time they post a message it gets reset to an hour later.

That way posters stay logged in and lurkers get bumped off.

On load:

```
response.cookies("chatuser")=nickname
response.cookies("chatuser").expires=now()+0.5
```

On post a message:

```
response.cookies("chatuser").expires=now()+0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using Forms Authentication and that the authentication cookie is expiring as well.

Each time a request is sent to the application and the current session is still valid the session timeout will be renewed.

Forms Authentication can work in two ways. You can keep a user logged in for a fixed amount of time or use a sliding expiration. For example:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
        loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="15" />
</authentication>
```

The above sets the forms authentication timeout to 15 minutes but also enables the sliding expiration (`slidingExpiration="true"`. Provided a user revisits the site within 15 minutes the cookie lifetime will be extended and the user will stay authenticated.

If `slidingExpiration="false"` then a user will be kicked off after 15 minutes regardless of when they last accessed the site.

It's also a good idea to have the Forms Authentication cookie expire slightly earlier than the 
Session timeout. This means users get kicked off before encountering null Session data if it's the other way around.

Comment: where does this code go? The chat page doesn't use any form submission but uses Ajax to grab the form field data and post it. Also it's the ASP script called by the ajax which checks if the session has expired and if it has it sends back data which pops up an alert telling the user they've been logged out. The actual ASP script used by Ajax doesn't require the user to be logged in so it never generates an error.

Comment: @derek - my apologies, I assumed you were using ASP.NET.

Comment: @derek - so definitely classic ASP and not ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually sending any cookie information with your AJAX requests?

If the AJAX requests don't contain the Session ID that is placed in a cookie by ASP then the requests will not maintain the session regardless of how frequent they are.

Comment: I'm not sure - it will depend on the code you are using to do the AJAX requests and how much control over the HTTP request you have